# After the Flink version is upgraded, the taskmanager log information cannot be seen in the web UI

Tags: apache-flink

After the Flink version is upgraded, the taskmanager log information can not be seen in the web UI. In `stdout`, you can see the log of the code itself, but can not see the log of Spring and Flink itself.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version have you upgraded to, and how is Flink running (i.e., Yarn, Kubernetes, standalone, etc)?

With some versions of Flink in certain environments, the logs aren't available in the web UI because they are being aggregated elsewhere. For example, you will want to use something like `kubectl logs` to access the logs if you are running on Kubernetes with certain versions of Flink.

**UPDATE**

Flink 1.11 switched from log4j1 to log4j2. See [the release notes](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.11/release-notes/flink-1.11.html#switch-to-log4j-2-by-default-flink-15672) for details. Also, the logging properties file `log4j-yarn-session.properties` was renamed to `log4j-session.properties` and `yarn-session.sh` was updated to use the new file.  Again, see [the release notes](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.11/release-notes/flink-1.11.html#renamed-log4j-yarn-sessionproperties-and-logback-yarnxml-properties-files-flink-17527) for more info.

Comment: thank you very much! This problem has been solved.

The reason for the error is that the log framework conflicts. I introduced the logback dependency in the pom file. After removing this dependency, the log can be viewed normally in webui.